# Controlling two fixtures on same circuit independently

Tags: electrical, switch, fans

I currently have an existing loud bathroom and a ceiling light on he same circuit. The wiring goes from the switch to the ceiling box and then to the fan. Both of these are controlled by the same switch. The fan is quite loud and not necessary much of the time when the bathroom is being used. I was wondering if there are any remote controlled type switches that could be used to indepentandaly control the fan and the light. I understand that for the fan to be turned on it will be neccesary to also have the light on. I really just want a way to have the light on **without** having to have the fan running. I don't mind adding another switch to the box, however, I don't want to rip out the walls/ceiling to run another wire from the switch to the fan.

I know there are remote controlled switches to control ceiling fans and ceiling-fan light kits, like the Lutron MA-LFQHW-WH Maestro Dual Digital Dimmer / Fan Control. If there was space in the ceiling lamp, maybe something like this could work?

Answer (score 2):

Without running an additional switched hot lead, it can be done using radio frequency transmitting switches which control a RF receiver/relay which you would have to wire into the ceiling box. [Leviton makes devices like that](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/SectionDisplay.jsp?section=37824&minisite=10251). They are neither simple nor cheap. In my opinion it would be easier, quicker, and cheaper to fish a new wire or even open the wall. Patching is painstaking and tedious but not difficult.